# One Form To Many Forms

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have form with 1 button. when you click on the button 3 others appear which relate to product colours red green or blue.

At the moment when you click on a colour button it opens a form just for that colour product.

Is it possible to have just one colour form that opens when any colour button is clicked but will filter the parts related to the colour.

Comment: I think the short answer is yes, but without seeing your code I don't know what specific answer might be available to your problem.

Comment: Please clarify if you are programming in Access or in VB6. If the former, you should delete the VB6 tag and replace it with VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for the OpenForm method of DoCmd include Where, so you can have something like:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "FormNameHere",,,"Colour='" & Me.txtBoxWithColourName & "'"
```

Comment: but is this a VB6 frontend or an Access frontend?

Comment: There is a great deal of confusion about VBA and VB6, I strongly suspect VBA. In fact, I am almost certain, given the poster.